# PIC programming with command line

Tags: pic

Has anyone programmed a PIC using the command line interface with a batch? I have Pickit 4 and I've tried this:

```
@echo off & setLocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo Flashing with PIC ...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\MPLABX\v5.30\mplab_platform\mplab_ipe\ipecmd.exe" /P16F1783 /F"C:\Users\xpp\Desktop\pic.hex" /TPPK4 /E /M /OL /W
```

I'm getting this error and also it's pretty slow:

[image]

EDIT:
To get it working from external power supply, we have to remove the /W command.

```
@echo off & setLocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo Flashing with PIC ...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\MPLABX\v5.30\mplab_platform\mplab_ipe\ipecmd.exe" /P16F1783 /F"C:\Users\xpp\Desktop\pic.hex" /TPPK4 /E /M /OL
```

Comment: Have you made certain that you don't have external power on the device?

Comment: I had external power supply, so I removed the /W command. Just edited my question. The only issue with this method is it's pretty slow, it takes a minute to connect to the Pickit 4.

Comment: The command line tool seems to execute in a specific Java Runtime Environment. The virus scanners at work appear to open every JAR archive and scan the code to malware. Could be why your script runs slow.